# Assign coordinates of an image to variables on a mouse click

Tags: python

The following code gives me the x and y coordinates of an image on a mouse click event.  I want to assign the x and y coordinates to global variables `x` and `y` instead of printing them and then close the image.  How do I do this please?

```
%matplotlib tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))

img=mpimg.imread(workingimage)

def onclick(event):
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(ix, iy)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign the values to 2 global variables and call `plt.close()`:

```py
%matplotlib tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))

img = mpimg.imread(workingimage)

def onclick(event):
    global clicked_on_x, clicked_on_y
    clicked_on_x, clicked_on_y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    plt.close()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
print("clicked on position", clicked_on_x, clicked_on_y)

# rest of code
```

Answer (score 1):

So I modified your code so that it works:

```
#%matplotlib tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import time

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))

img=mpimg.imread(working_image)


def onclick(event):
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    #global x,y
    #x,y = ix,iy
    #print(ix, iy)
    plt.close() #closing the figure
    get_x(ix,iy)

def get_x(pX,pY):
    print("X-Coordinate: " + str(pX))
    print("Y-Coordinate: " + str(pY))

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

The changes:

Handing `ix,iy` to the next Funktion that needs them as parameters. You could assign them as global, then you don't need the parameters, but global variables should be avoided

the line `plt.close(fig)` closes the figure named `fig`

So I hope that answers all your questions

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Unfortunately, when I click on the image `x` I still showing value of 0

Comment: Was able to reproduce the Error, gonna check that on Monday

Comment: You may want to read [this section](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) of the variables and scope page of the documentation.

Comment: Yea, silly mistake..., I edited my answer so that it works now if you really want to use your variables globally, JohanC shows that in his answer. I edited my answer to an option where I handle them as parametres and just hand them to the next method...
thx William Miller